# Event emitter function not called in angular 11

Tags: angular

I have used the event emitter for event binding in angular.

Its not calling the function which in mentioned in component

In conversation-card.component.ts

```
@Output() badgeAwarded = new EventEmitter();


this.chatApiService.addBadge(data).subscribe(response =>{
      this.snackBarService.success(this.translate.instant('SECOND_ITERATION.BADGE_AWARDED'))
      this.badgeAwarded.emit(true);
    })
```

In my-request-details.component.html file

```
<app-conversation-card
              (badgeAwarded)="awardBadges($event)"
            ></app-conversation-card>
```

In my-request-details.component.ts file

```
awardBadges(value){
    console.log(value);
  }
```

awardBadges function not called while emit have checked in console tab in browser.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz? the code seems right.

Comment: `
this.chatApiService.addBadge(data).subscribe(response =>{
      this.snackBarService.success(this.translate.instant('SECOND_ITERATION.BADGE_AWARDED'))
      this.badgeAwarded.emit(true);
    })` are you subscribing this in onInit?

Comment: sorry cant provide that my office project

Comment: no iam not calling this on ngOninit. Its called when user submit the form.

Comment: ok..usually when i work with observable i try always to subscribe observable in onInit. in your case, you can cast a Subject when the user submit the form, subscribe this in onInit and use a switchMap to do the api's call. beacuse the only thing that can be happening is a strange beahvior of rxjs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I encounter this issue, my problem is the same everytime:

Importing the `EventEmitter` and `Output` from a wrong source, possibly `protractor`. So make sure it's from the correct source:

```js
import { EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: I have added in conversation-card component ts file  import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, ViewChild,TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

Comment: Yes and make sure it's the only `EventEmitter` that you're importing

Comment: Do you import `Output` from anywhere else?

Comment: yes i have send the data to child component

Comment: you mean the parent component, right? Because Output sends it to the top level component, which is the parent

Comment: import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component,  Input, OnInit, Output,EventEmitter, ViewChild,TemplateRef } from '@angular/core'; i have already imported this

Comment: Are you importing `Output` or `EventEmitter` from anywhere else but the thing you texted?

Comment: I have imported as per mentioned

Comment: Can you post more of your component then? Maybe the whole method where subscribe is called? And where is it being called from?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the code inside of the `subscribe` block runs?

```
this.chatApiService.addBadge(data).subscribe(response =>{
      this.snackBarService.success(this.translate.instant('SECOND_ITERATION.BADGE_AWARDED'))
      // make sure you see this log
      console.log('!! Emitting badAwarded !!');
      this.badgeAwarded.emit(true);
    })
```

Comment: I have added the console bottom and above of this.badgeAwarded.emit(true);

Comment: Ok, check out `eko`'s suggestion. I think that can be it.